# Google indexing pages with #! although we don't have any

Tags: seo, google-search, javascript, ajax

Our company has developed a [Single Page Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) using AngularJS and its routing. Google indexed our site decently with JavaScript but it did not index some pages very well so we have developed an HTML only version.

We have followed the [Ajax Crawling Specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) posted here and have a `<meta name='fragment' content='!'>` tag and canonical urls. We expect `http://www.example.com/foo/bar` to be fetched from `http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/foo/bar`.

However, we have found out that when we rolled the AJAX specification we now have all pages indexed twice, once with the JavaScript version as `http://www.example.com/foo/bar` and once with the new version as `http://www.example.com/#!/foo/bar`. This is harmful to us since it's duplicate content and also mis-representing out site.

I have tried looking for similar questions here and in the Google product forum but could not come up with anything.

Comment: Have you raised this issue with Google? On their forum?

Comment: @JVerstry yes - I have done that immediately after I posted this question: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?notifsrc=REVQRFUET48ogigKqiiqmQ#!msg/webmasters/zrjK9NEtQSc/XK9iG7cvNrcJ However my first assumptions is that we did not understand the protocol correctly rather than something is wrong with their product so my chances of getting help here are fairly decent in addition to this question being relevant to a large target audience here (Everyone with a single page application that doesn't use #! in the URLS and want Google to index them). Thanks for the suggestion by the way.

Comment: Did you define [canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) through `rel="canonical"`?

Comment: @KasperSouren yes, I added a link to the site but a mod removed it - you can find it in an earlier revision of this question.  We have indeed added canonical links to all the SEO friendly pages.

Comment: When I go to an address with `!#` on your site (`#!/stocks/VMED`) I'm redirected to the version without `!#`, then I get an error and I don't see the `ref="canonical"` link in your HTML.

Comment: @KasperSouren thanks, the #! urls are just supposed to redirect it's not supposed to be used. We have canonical URLs on the scanned SEO friendly pages. Try going to `http://www.tipranks.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/stocks/VMED` with your useragent set to `Googlebot/2.1` for instance.

Comment: redirecting the #! urls and cloaking the ugly urls does not seem like you are following the specification.

Comment: Just wondering, if you aren't using `#!` URLs, why are you using `_escaped_fragment_` and the Google AJAX spec?

Comment: @w3d because we have a lot of AJAX based content and we want to make sure Google is indexing all of it.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, use `rel="canonical"`. This could be as simple as  putting `<link rel="canonical" href="http://blog.example.com/dresses/green-dresses-are-awesome" />` in your `<head>`. [See Google for more info.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

This won't keep bots from crawling both "versions", but it will tell Google (and other SERPs) to only index the canonical document.

Comment: In that same vein, can he use a robots.txt file??

Comment: We have those, they did not help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand about javascript.
In **Google indexing**, us the canonical url in `<head>` like @philtune says. But if you can't expect `http://www.example.com/foo/bar` to be fetched from `http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/foo/bar` . 
**Google Fetch** just fetched the `canonical url`.

In this case, the url is `http://www.example.com/foo/bar`, google will index `http://www.example.com/foo/bar` too.

If you want Google index you're page, add this script in `<head>`:

```
<meta content='index, follow' name='googlebot'/>
```

and then fetch again using the `Google Fetch`.

`Note`: 
google will crwal and follow and crawl the website and follow all links on the page. If in you're page have a link like `http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/foo/bar` and redirect to `http://www.example.com/foo/bar`, google will index `http://www.example.com/foo/bar` because `http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/foo/bar` are redirect to `http://www.example.com/foo/bar`.