# Make Google crawl ajax contents but not link to them directly

Tags: seo, ajax

I noticed that Google search results for one of my sites link directly to ajax request pages, so I put them on robots.txt. However, doing this makes Google not crawl the contents at all (checked using Google Webmaster Tool).

Is there any way to make Google still crawl the ajax contents as a part of the main website contents, but not link to the ajax request links directly?

Comment: Google wants relevant results, if you have information the user is searching for then Google will expect to return those results for the user not visit this page then click button... So yes, Google will attempt to index aJax content... and if you block it, Google will not reward for the information stored via a Ajax request.

Comment: All the AJAX are on load. 

I was afraid this isn't possible. I just dislike having direct links to the AJAX pages that has no layouts (kinda like the old days of websites with frames and having Google links the individual pages, but missing the navigation frame...)

Comment: Possibly related: [Google indexing pages with #! although we don't have any](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68415/google-indexing-pages-with-although-we-dont-have-any)